# Dockerized Oracle schema gone after docker-compose down

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I discovered my Dockerized Oracle freshly re-created the whole schema (tables, packages etc) as I do docker-compose up -d oracle. And sadly lost all my local data T_T

The schema is automatically created as the container is up for the first time. Some materials I have read says that, docker-compose down will undo whatever docker-compose up does.

I like to know if that is true and if that is related to my issue?

below is my volume's configuration for Oracle in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ${HOST_PATH}/config/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - ${HOST_PATH}/config/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  - ${HOST_PATH}/config/scripts/:/scripts/:ro
  - oracle_data:/opt/oracle/oradata
  # Setup data pump directory to initialize the database
  - ${HOST_PATH}/test-data/prebuilt/:/prebuilt/
  - ${HOST_PATH}/test-data/datapump/:/datapump/
  - ${HOST_PATH}/config/oracle/ora-init-scripts/:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup
```

I am not sure but I am thinking the main data is not mounted to external with this configuration
      - oracle_data:/opt/oracle/oradata
hence internal volume will get destroyed as its container gets destroyed with docker-compose down?

Comment: Have you researched Docker Volumes? Stopping a container should not destroy data.

Comment: Doing docker-compose stop does not destroy data. But what about docker-compose down?  I have put my volume's configuration in the question.

Comment: A quick google search will tell you that `down` removes containers/volumes.

Comment: what I know is docker-compose down will remove containers but only with argument -v it will also remove volumes. And I never did the down with -v..

Comment: That is odd. I expect your volumes (at least for oracle_data) to be working correctly. Possibly oracle data directory is set to another location? You didn't post your image/compose file so cannot determine. You could also do a `docker volume inspect oracle_data` and check the contents of the volume based on the `MountPath`.

Comment: It's not so much a question of `docker compose` and what's it doing but what your volumes were and whether you persisted the database datafiles. That on the other hand highly depends on which Docker image you are using and where the data files have been put. By default, Oracle Database will put all your database data files under `$ORACLE_HOME/oradata/$ORACLE_SID` and as long as that survives, your data does as well. Looking at the above, I don't see any `oradata` or similar in your volume configuration. Which Docker image are you using and where do the database data files reside?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose down` does destroy volumes created from within the corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file. You can either create the volume externally or explicitly specify the server's directory that should back your volume. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906856/keep-redis-data-alive-between-docker-compose-down-and-up-in-docker-container) provides a working example.