# Keep Redis data alive between docker-compose down and up in Docker container

Tags: django, docker, redis

Question is about keeping `Redis` data alive between `docker-compose up`  and `docker-compose down.`

In the `docker-compose.yaml` file bellow `db` service uses      - `postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` volume to keep data alive.
I would like to do something like this for `redis` service but I can not find workable solution to do so. Only one way I have managed to achieve this goal is to store data in local storage  `- ./storage/redis/data:/data.` All experiments with external volume gave no results.

Question is  -is it possible somehow to store redis data between `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` in a volume likewise  it made in `DB` service?

Sorry if question is naive…

Thanks

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - ./series/.env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres.dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./series/.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1q2w3e
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    ports:
      - target: 6379
        published: 6380
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
        - ./storage/redis/data:/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master

volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You just need to add a named volume for Redis data next to the `postgres_data`:

```yaml
volumes:
    postgres_data:
    redis_data:
```

Then change host path to the named volume:

```yaml
  redis:
    ...
    volumes:
        - redis_data:/data
```

If Redis saved data with host path, then the above will work for you. I mention that because you have to configure Redis to enable persistent storage (see Redis Docker Hub page https://hub.docker.com/_/redis).

Beware, running `docker-compose down -v` will destroy volumes as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No need to configure nothing. It seems like persistent storage works by default

Comment: I was having a similar issue. I had my volumes set correctly, but Redis was not persisting. The link to the docker Redis page was the answer I needed.